# Test every view searching or missing translations span.translation_missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am developing a rails app, and I want to test every view to know if there is any missing translation. I can do it by adding `assert_select "span.translation_missing", false` on every view on controller or integration tests, but I want to follow the DRY principle. Is there a way to do it without having to write the assertion code on every view in controller tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Rails 4.1.0 and higher you can use `config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations`.

```
# app/config/environments/test.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # ...
  # Raises error for missing translations
  config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

This won't actually automatically "test every view" in your application but it will tell you if there are any missing translations as it renders the views. You actually need to write integration tests that cover each view anyways.

Note that controller tests are not a good idea for this. They don't render views unless you explicitly configure it and are depreciated in favour of integration tests. System tests where you simulate the users path through the application will also cover this.